# Shape class for border points in java

Tags: java

I want to use shape to diagnose the **border points** in a map, How can i use this class in java for diagnosing these points so that i can put something on these areas or move something on them ? How can i do it ?

Answer (score 0):

FlatteningPathIterator

From comment
 * The `FlatteningPathIterator` class returns a flattened view of
 * another {@link PathIterator} object.  Other {@link java.awt.Shape Shape} 
 * classes can use this class to provide flattening behavior for their paths
 * without having to perform the interpolation calculations themselves.